# Responsive website width 960px or in %?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Truthfully, I am quite a novice in website building, although I have read 7 books about it already. Responsive webdesign from Ethan Marcotte being the last one, which is great.

I am stuck with one question though. If you build a website responsive and instead of using pixels, you use %. Then how wide does the wrapper have to be? Should I give the wrapper a max-width of 960px and all the other frames, like header, nav, etc, convert them into %? So for example the header will be 900/960×100=93.75%.

Or do I have to make the wrapper in % as well. My initial thought was dividing 960 by my monitor's resolution, which is 1680 px wide, so that will be 960 / 1680 × 100 = 57%.

That number doesn't sound logical, because with extra large screens it won't look right or does it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Reinier

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not logical. It's not safe to hardcode pixel sizes, except possibly for very small elements, because you cannot assume anything about what kind of screen your user is using.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few reasons to hard code pixel sizes, even images can be placed wonderfully without the need of a hard width and height. Try to use percentages when you can, but also remember media queries are a wonderful thing!